# Roboelectric test edittext with inputfilter

Tags: android, regex, robolectric

I'm running some tests to check if the data is filled right in the fields.
In the name field, I've a input filter with this regex "**[A-ZÀ-ÚA-Za-zà-úûÛ-Üa-zä\\s’]***", but when the field is filled in test environment, the regex is not matching the name ("Bruno Pinto").

I get the regex from the XML inside my custom view.
To do that I use:

```
 TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.FloatLabelLayout,
            0, 0);
```

If I debug this line in test environment:

```
        final String regex = a.getString(R.styleable.FloatLabelLayout_regex);
```

regex = "[A-ZÀ-ÚA-Za-zà-úûÛ-Üa-zä\\s’]"

If I debug the same line in normal run environment:

regex = "[A-ZÀ-ÚA-Za-zà-úûÛ-Üa-zä\s’]"

Someone knows what I've to do to make this works?

InputFilter

```
 InputFilter[] inputFilter = new InputFilter[]{
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength),
            new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                    if (src.equals("") || regex == null) { // for backspace
                        return src;
                    }
                    if (src.toString().matches(regex)) {
                        return src;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
    };
```

Test

```
  @Test
public void testFillName() {
    fragment.setData(getUser());
    assertEquals("Name right", getUser().fullName, ((FloatLabelLayout) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.personal_name)).getText());
}
```

Comment: i think you need to add a space inside your square brackets

Comment: Where is your test? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I do remember there was issue with `Robolectric` and styled attributes. Can you try to just hardcode your regexp and check if it is working after (just for test)